# Will MVC timeout if EF Code First takes a while updating the DB due to indexing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

**Environment:**
I have an MVC application that is using the Entity Framework 6.1. The database I am working with is extremely large and will contain many indexed tables and views.

**Concern**
When the application starts, due to it being code first, it'll update the database as we've asked it to (Not the concern). My concern is, with it being a web application, the application will time out, not finish updating the database, and create a corrupted DB.

**Question**
So when I go to add or update views that contain indexes, will I run into an internet timeout issue?  So say if, because of the indexes, it takes 15 to 25 minutes to run, is that a cause for concern, or does MVC and EF know how to handle that?

Should we, when we update a client, manually go on their server and run a separate sql file that updates and adds the indexing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is really 15-25 minutes then I would not risk letting users access the application while the database is indexing. I would switch off the web app, reindex the database offline and turn on the app.

And no, neither MVC not EF know how to handle that automatically.

Technically, you could **possibly** increase the command timeout for the database migrator so that the migration would not timeout but the database would not operate normally during reindexing anyway.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrationsconfiguration.commandtimeout(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Ok thanks! I think that's what we'll do. Whenever we update someone, we'll separate the indexing, and still let the application start update the database. Then we'll run a separate script file that will add the indexing since that's what takes so long.